# Where to store defaults asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have bunch of default strings and ints throughout the app. like default names, etc,etc. Those are all constants. I just want to access them in different pages in my app. What is the best place to place them? I was thinking about Enum or something similar. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place is to put them into the appSettings section of your web.config file:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
  </appSettings>
```

You can then read the key/value pairs using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx#Y400) class:

```
' Get the AppSettings section.        
' This function uses the AppSettings property
' to read the appSettings configuration 
' section.
Public Shared Sub ReadAppSettings()
    Try
        ' Get the AppSettings section.
        Dim appSettings As NameValueCollection = _
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

        ' Get the AppSettings section elements.
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Using AppSettings property.")
        Console.WriteLine("Application settings:")

        If appSettings.Count = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine( _
            "[ReadAppSettings: {0}]", _
            "AppSettings is empty Use GetSection first.")
        End If
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < appSettings.Count
            Console.WriteLine( _
                "#{0} Key: {1} Value: {2}", _
                i, appSettings.GetKey(i), appSettings(i))
            System.Math.Max( _
                System.Threading.Interlocked. _
                Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While
    Catch e As ConfigurationErrorsException
        Console.WriteLine("[ReadAppSettings: {0}]", _
                          e.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: "best" -- not necessarily.  But certainly a valid and tenable option.

Comment: True - might not be the fastest, but it gives you flexibility: no re-compilation if a value changes, and the web.config file can be customized for dev/QA/production.

Comment: not exactly true about "no re-compilation if a value changes"  .Net will happily recompile the site it the web.config changes...  A better phrase would be "no code redeployment if a value changes"

Answer (score 1):

You could simply create a static class with each public const.

```
static public class DefaultValues
{
    public const string Name = "Bob";
    public const int AppId = 1234;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep things like this in the project's Settings area (*Project Properties* -> *Settings*) and then access them throughout my code as `My.Settings.<TheSettingName>` in a strongly-typed manor.

Also as a bonus, it puts each of these settings then in the `web.config` file, where I could then change their values at runtime if need-be, without the need to recompile/deploy.

The downside of this is that `My.Settings.<...>` isn't available right from the view/aspx.  So for values that I need right in the view, I wrap them in an accessor module.  E.g.

```vb
Public Module ScriptReferences
    Public Function JQueryJsUrl() As String
        Return My.Settings.JQueryJsUrl
    End Function
End Module
```

and then in the view/aspx you can simply call `ScriptReferences.JQueryJsUrl` to get your value.

Comment: Yeah, I remember I was using this thing once but cannot find it on a web app.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have some kind of definitions file. However, be careful with approach, as you can easily get an unmanageable definitions file if you keep adding random constants to it.

Answer (score 0):

I generally create a constants class or some other appropriately named static class and then put static get only properties for the various constants.

```
public static string ConstantString { get {return "Hello World"; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the App_GlobalRessource with resource file ... That way those constant can be easily maintained.